# Winter Bash inspiration == Team Fortress 2 hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

I understand it's just for fun, and it's an achievement / reward system. Out of curiosity, did the Stack Exchange staff get the idea after playing [Team Fortress 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Fortress_2) (TF2)?

Comment: whatever i love that(hats) ... and its makes me happy

Comment: Dont you mean `Winter Bash inspiration == TF2 hats` ;)

Comment: Damn it! I was so hoping that inspiration came from Jægerdom of GirlGenius universe... http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Magnificent_Hat http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20100521

Comment: @yentup Good point. Fixed it :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Probably*.

The event first happened on <s>Gaming.SE</s> Arqade last year, and the [blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) announcing it starts with:

> Throughout history, men have worn hats as a way of showing how much better they are than other men. “I buy hats,” a behatted man seems to say. “I am better than you.”
>
> In wartime, hats were a useful way of conferring rank, and ensuring that casualties were confined to the lower classes… During peacetime, hats have been instrumental for men to let the non-hatted know just who is wearing the hat around here.
>
> – [The Team Fortress 2 Classless Update](http://www.teamfortress.com/classless/day01.php)

Comment: It's at least a *somewhat* safe assumption. (Hat Dash predates my employment, so I don't actually know for sure.)

Comment: Just when I thought I escaped the things, they came back for me! Now if you had a trading system in place for hats...

Comment: I can confirm this -- when we did this on Gaming in 2011, it was wholly inspired by XBox and TF2. We've got a few TF2 diehards in the company, and the main proponent for hats inside was someone who *really loved that game*.