# Images of the hats from Arqade's 2011 Hat Dash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

The present Winter Bash started out in 2011 on Gaming Stack Exchange exclusively [as "Hat Dash"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270981/what-is-the-origin-and-thought-process-behind-the-tradition-of-hats).

All the images of the hats that year seem to be located in a PNG file: http://hatdash.com/content/img/hats128.png. (On Gaming SE Meta, there are *only* images of the 6 secret hats.)

Unfortunately, the PNG file isn't archived on the Wayback Machine and the [archived site of hatdash.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20120108015416/http://hatdash.com:80/) doesn't have the images either.

So, does anyone, who has been on SE long enough, happen to have the images of the hats used during Hat Dash? And if they're kind enough to share them in an answer? I'm just really curious to see the design of old hats.

<sup>And fun fact: at least 2 hats from Hat Dash were reused last year & this year.</sup>

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Special thanks to balpha for finding this, here ya go! Some of these have made comebacks in later years, so they'll look familiar. I *don't* have all of the names of each individual hat, but folks on Gaming could probably completely label the list.

[image: Hat images]

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! I didn't think anyone would bother to find them, really appreciate it! :D

Comment: Diamond helmet ( a reference to Minecraft) ???

Answer (score 6):

You can see a large selection of them at the [hatdash site](http://hatdash.com/promos/2/hat-dash):

[image: hat rack 2011]

However, I'm not aware of any pictures of *all* the hats.