# Why does hatdash.com show the SO contests page but not redirect to it?

Tags: support, bug, redirection, hat-dash

[hatdash.com](http://hatdash.com/) was used for [Arqade's Hat Dash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270981/what-is-the-origin-and-thought-process-behind-the-tradition-of-hats).

Currently, the site shows the SO contests page but does not **redirect** to it.

Since past Winter Bash sites all redirect to the contests page, is there a particular reason why the Hat Dash site doesn't?