# Does the '10' in some of the hat triggers mean anything?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

There are two new hats with a 10 in their trigger:

- [Rep Hunter](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter): 10 answers in 1 day with positive scores
- [Matryoshka](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/matryoshka): 10 successful close or reopen votes

There might be secret hats qualifying for this as well, but we don't know all triggers yet.

I'm just curious, but is this a reference to the fact that this is the 10th time that we're hunting for hats? While this is only the [9th Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash/info), it all started with [Hat Dash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270983/295232) in 2011. Or am I overthinking this too much?

Comment: Almost sure you're overthinking it, but... who knows! :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a reference to @ShadowtheHatterWizard 10th anniversary avatar... that some dev didn't doublecheck and though was Stack 10th anniversary :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No

> adding this haiku
> so that min characters reached
> you're over thinking

Answer (score 8):

Hardly an official answer, but I think you're overthinking it.

10 is a nice round number that was also featured more than once in past winter bashes, e.g.:

- Just Jesting for 10 upvoted comments (2019, 2017, 2012)
- Cosmic Brain for an answer with a score of 10 (2019, 2017)
- Like Clockwork for visiting a site on 10 consecutive days (2017)
- This is fine for deleting 10 of your own comments (2017, 2016)
- Blue in the Face for 10 upvoted comments (2016)
- Amazing Grace for asking a question with a score of 10 and getting an answer with a score of 10 (2015)
- Cleanup Crew for deleting 10 of your own comments (2015)